# Android Activity LifeCycle: Workload on onResume(), onStart(), onPause() and onStop()

Tags: android, lifecycle

What operations can be done under all states of lifecycle and
How to effectively use the callbacks of activity lifecycle?

For example, initialization of views can be done in onCreate(), animation can be started in onResume().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this if you haven't already: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

One thing I definitely suggest if you are using cursors or simplecursoradapters in your applications is to close the cursors and detach the cursors from your adapters in the onpause, and then reattach them in the onresume method

Comment: What operations can be performed on onStop() callback?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tutorial for reading the life-cycle of Android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks

see the figure1 and figure2 this will help you a lot for understand life-cycle of Android.